# missing 127.0.0.1 (loopback address)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, loopback-address

Ubuntu linux, 14.04 (DigitalOcean)

```
$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 04:01:1f:4c:XX:XX  
          inet addr:128.199.XXX.XXX  Bcast:128.199.XXX.255  Mask:255.255.192.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::601:1fff:XXXX:XXX/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1565 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1603 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:228014 (228.0 KB)  TX bytes:260483 (260.4 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          LOOPBACK  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I cannot find 127.0.0.1 in loopback.

Can I recover 127.0.0.1?

```
$ ping 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

It's no response long time.

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your
# system and how to activate them. For more information, see
# interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 128.199.XXX.XXX
        netmask 255.255.XXX.0
        gateway 128.199.XXX.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8 209.244.0.3
```

/etc/network/interfaces. it's default.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, it is solved.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo reboot now

$ ping 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.031 ms
```